# Saving zip file entry into a list

Tags: c#

I have a List and I want to save several pictures into it, then I will binary serialize that list into a file.

I am getting the pictures from a zip file like this:

```
zip.GetEntry(path).Open()
```

The zip file opens correctly and if i replace Open with ExtractToFile and try to extract the picture into a folder it works with no problems.

But when I try to save the body of the picture into the list instead, as a stream, it doesn't work:

```
List.Add(zip.GetEntry(path).Open());
```

The picture is over 2MB large, yet when I serialize the list it has barely 2 kilobytes.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `zip.GetEntry(path).Open()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly serialize a `Stream` object. You should first `Read` the contents into `byte[]`, then serialize that array.

First change your `List`:

```
List<byte[]> List = new List<byte[]>();
```

Then read the streams into this list. Since the `Length` property is not supported on compression streams, it is simpler to use a `MemoryStream` as a buffer:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    zip.GetEntry(path).Open().CopyTo(ms);
    List.Add(ms.ToArray());
}
```

And finally serialize the `List`.

Answer (score 3):

[ZipArchiveEntry.Open()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a stream.

You need to read the stream using [Stream.Read(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) method somewhere in your code.

You can save a list of streams if you want as long as you **read** them when you want to export the data.
The stream itself isn't the data, it allows you to read it.